# Convert 0 to 1 and Vice Versa

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, bit-manipulation

I was asked in an interview : how to convert 0 to 1 and 1 to 0. I answered :

1. Simple `if` and `switch`
2. Bit flipping.

Are there any other approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "bit flipping", specifically?

Comment: Didn't knew that Java is language agnostic. Cool.

Comment: @Balus: natural-language-agnostic maybe ;-)

Comment: Well, java code is preferred, but this is really not about java.

Comment: Well did they say you missed some or say you were wrong?

Comment: The question is vague. What do you mean? Because the way it reads, my answer would be "add 1 to 0, and subtract 1 from 1".

Comment: In terms of evaluating a canditate, what does this interview question show?

Comment: what's the input domain? switch(i){ case 0: return 1; default: return 0; }? or is anything other than [0,1] supposed to raise holy hell?

Comment: drelihan: It's a test to see if they're an architecture astronaut, or a programmer.  They're looking to see if you draw a UML diagram and start talking about WSDL.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A few obvious possibilities:

```
!n
1-n
n^1
n==0
n!=1
n<1
```

Comment: `!n` isn't reliably 1 => 0, 0 => 1 in a language agnostic way (in some languages, !0 = -1); in Java, it doesn't even work ("operator ! cannot be applied to int").

Comment: @GregS:good point...I've removed that one, and added a couple of others.

Comment: 1-n and -n + 1 are exactly the same in different ordering, kind of redundant.

Comment: T.J. Crowder, if ! meant to be bitwise NOT then in Java it's represented by ~ (tilda)

Comment: @Totophil No, 0 ^ 1 = 1 and 0 ^ 0 = 0, so it does not flip it correctly, whereas 1 ^ 1 = 0 and 0 ^ 1 = 1, so n ^ 1 is correct.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:quite true -- almost no notation you can use is truly language agnostic. I don't think any of these is legal Scheme -- so of course I wrote in the one true language and ignored the "Java" tag as an obvious mistake. :-)

Comment: Brandon Bodnár, that's not true. Please use a calculator if you must. Any number in power of 0 gives one, any number in the power of 1 gives itself.

Comment: @Totophil , ^ is the xor operator in most languages.

Comment: @Brandon, ok I can see now, I owe you an apology: sorry. Then we really have two ways of flipping the number here: (n XOR 1) and (0 in power of n).

Comment: Of these, only `1-n` and `n xor 1` are language agnostic in the sense that they deal with integer values. All others mix integers with boolean results, making them unsuitable for strongly-typed languages.

Comment: @Totophil: if ^ is the power operator, then 0 ^ 0 is undefined (mathematically, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Power.html).

Comment: @Greg, true in theory, nonetheless for most practical purposes absolute majority of implementations resolve 0 ^ 0 = 1. On the other hand n==0,  
n!=1 and n<1 are relational operations and in most modern languages will result in boolean value, not flip the 0 to 1 and back. This and the fact that boolean true and false won't always be represented in memory by 1 and 0 might lead to a very intresting discussion during the interview. The expressions would work in C because language creators took a shortcut in representing boolean values to simplify language syntax for compiler builders.

Comment: You forgot modulus: (3 + n) % 2

Comment: Which one is the best?

Comment: @蔡易翔 lacking  specific reason to do otherwise,  I'd probably use 1-n.

Answer (score 51):

Simple arithmetic:

```
x = 1 - x;
```

Actually, there are an infinite number of polynomials that will map 1 to 0 and vice versa.  For example:

```
x = x * x * x * x * x - x * x * x * x + x * x - 2 * x + 1;
```

Comment: Simplifies to `x^5 - x^4 + x^2 - 2x + 1`. But `x^n = x` for `x = 0 or 1`, so it further  simplifies to `x - x + x -2x + 1` which is just `1 - x`. (In case anyone was unsure if they could actually use the second polynomial.)

Comment: ARGH - why didn't I think of this ? +(1 - 0)

Answer (score 21):

Lookup table:

```
int[] swap = { 1, 0 };
```

And later:

```
x = swap[x];
```

Comment: What's wrong with this? The OP asked for any alternative methods.

Comment: This is a totally awesome answer. I like it because its the least mathematical. Also unlike the other answers this will fail if the domain and range are outside of 0-1 ala fail fast although not gracefully.

+1

Answer (score 8):

Take a paper clip. Straighten it out. It's a 1. Bend it to meet its ends. It's a 0. To make it a 1, straighten it.

Comment: I don't think Java is powerful enough to do that.

Comment: @Adam: You probably need to find an embedded robot lisp to really do the job right. Only Embedded Robot Lisps have the power to truly transform 0s into 1s and vice-versa.

Comment: If you bend it too much it'll break and you'll have two, smaller paper clips you can use!

Answer (score 4):

they probably expected you to use bitwise NOT

Answer (score 4):

Some Trig:
COS(PI * N)^2

In python

```
import math
math.cos(math.pi * n)  ** 2
```

I can't believe people forgot modulus:

```
(3 + n) % 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do ABS(VAR - 1) but i think your approaches are more elegant

Answer (score 1):

This one isn't the best, but it works:

```
pow(0, n);
```

Comment: pow(0, 0) is mathematically undefined, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Power.html

Comment: Is Stephen Wolfram some kind of authority on math?  Take a look at this article to see a few differing opinions:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_zero_power

Comment: @Adam Doyle: Yeah, count on Wikipedia to present all points of view simultaneously. It's the internet equivalent of the [Total Perspective Vortex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Perspective_Vortex#Total_Perspective_Vortex).

Comment: I like this explanation http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-exponents-why-does-00-1/

Comment: It depends on what kind of math you are doing and kind of comes down to the question is there a "GUT" for math which I believe Godel made doubtful. A good book on this is "Is God a Mathematician?" http://www.amazon.com/God-Mathematician-Mario-Livio/dp/074329405X

I mean there are even some philosophers/mathematicians that think we should discount induction.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any two numbers...

(EDIT: looking at the other answers I may have misread the question... but I still like my answer :-)

```
public class X
{
    public static void main(final String[] argv)
    {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(argv[0]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(argv[1]);

        x += y;
        y = x - y;
        x = x - y;

        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used `-~-n` in JavaScript.
It converts 1 to -1 which is represented as `11111111`, then flips the bits to `00000000` which is 0. The second negative sign does not affect the 0. On the other hand, if `n` is 0, the first negative sign has no effect, the tilde flips the bits, and the second negative sign converts -1 to 1.

Comment: dodgy, but genius ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 0):

Array can also be used to do it as:
[Conversion using array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCj3j.jpg)

Using hashmap, it can done as:
[Conversion using Hashmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cU9S.jpg)